# How to fix Apache Cassandra connection issues?

Tags: database, cassandra, cqlsh

I tried accessing Apache Cassandra using **cqlsh**

But it returns with the error

```
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
```

Comment: Have you made any changes on Cassandra config file?  Are you using authentication to connect to?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple options:

a) using the IP address defined in your `cassandra.yaml` file in the key `listen_address`

```
# cat cassandra.yaml | grep listen_address:
listen_address: 172.1.2.3
# cqlsh 172.1.2.3
Connected to keyspace1 at 172.1.2.3:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.4 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]
Use HELP for help.
```

b) if you are using linux, the command [hostname](https://linux.die.net/man/1/hostname) can be helpful for this:

```
# cqlsh $(hostname)
Connected to keyspace1 at test-c-ca5d61df000b73cb4:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.4 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]
Use HELP for help.
```

c) get any IP address from the cluster with `nodetool status`

```
# nodetool status
Datacenter: us-east-vpc
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address        Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               
Rack
UN  172.1.2.3  4.7 GiB    256          33.1%             655da17a-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx  1d
UN  172.1.4.5  4.94 GiB   256          33.5%             23f18c46-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx  1c
UN  172.1.6.8  4.74 GiB   256          33.4%             f8ad0b6a-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx  1a
# cqlsh 172.1.6.8
Connected to keyspace1 at 172.1.6.8:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.4 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]
Use HELP for help.
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check what rpc_address and listen_address configured in cassandra.yaml then run the cqlsh command with port if you changed the default port. you will be able to connect the cassandra server.